# get "getDistance" from Location Class and use it in Target Class using an if condition

Tags: java

//The Location Class in a seperate file

```
package tld;
import java.util.*;
public class Location {
private double x;
private double y;
Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);

public Location(double x, double y){
x= scan.nextDouble();
y= scan.nextDouble();}

public double getX(){
return x;}

public double getY(){
return y;}

public void setX(double x){
this.x=x;}

public void setY(double y){
this.y=y;}

public String toString(){
return "Location: x= "+getX()+" ; y= "+getY();}

public double getDistance(Location L){ 
 double x1=scan.nextDouble();
 double y1=scan.nextDouble();
 L=new Location(x1,y1);
return (Math.sqrt((Math.pow((x-x1),2))+(Math.pow((y-y1), 2))));}
}
```

.

//The Target Class in a seperate file

```
package tld;
import java.util.*;
public class Target{
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
private Location loc;
private double speed;
private String type;
private boolean threat;
private int count = 0;

public Target(double x, double y, double speed){
    x=scan.nextDouble();
    y=scan.nextDouble();
    speed=scan.nextDouble();
    if(speed<500)
         type="Helicopter";
    else type="Jet"; 
    threat = false;
    count++;}

public String getType(){
    return type;}

public double getSpeed() {
    return speed;}

public void setSpeed(double speed) {
    this.speed = speed;}

public Location getLoc() {
    return loc;}

public void setLoc(Location loc) {
    this.loc = loc;}

public boolean isThreat(Location L){
     if(Location.getDistance()<100){
         threat=true;}
     else threat=false;
     return threat;}

public String toString(){
     return "Target is " + getType() + ", speed= " + getSpeed() + "mph, [Location: x=" + Location.x1+ "; y=" + Loc.x + "]";
}}
```

my error is in this class.. in the "boolean isThreat method"

.

//Main Driver in a seperate file and its still not finished

```
package tld;
import java.util.*;
public class TLD {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Location L = new Location(100,200);
System.out.println("please enter 4 targets");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String [] Target=new String[4];
for(int i=0; i<Target.length; i++)
Target[i]=scan.next();


}

}
```

note that i'm not allowed to use advanced commands or classes

Comment: Please clearly describe what is your error and what are you trying to obtain. Show only important fragments of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `getDistance` is not static, you need to have an instance of `Location` before you can call it. Luckily, you *do* have an instance. See the `loc` variable declared at the top of the class? That's what you need!

So change this line

```
if(Location.getDistance()<100){
```

to this:

```
if(loc.getDistance(L)<100){
```

"Why do I have to put the `L` there?" you might ask. That is because we are getting the distance between two locations! The first location is `loc` but what's the second location? From the method signature, I think you want `L`, the parameter, to be the second location.

Also, there are lots more places in your code that makes little sense. This is my *guess* of what you want to do:

```
public class Location {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public Location(double x, double y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public double getY(){
        return y;
    }

    public void setX(double x){
        this.x=x;
    }

    public void setY(double y){
        this.y=y;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Location: x= "+getX()+" ; y= "+getY();
    }

    public double getDistance(Location L){
        double x1=L.getX();
        double y1=L.getY();
        return (Math.sqrt((Math.pow((x-x1),2))+(Math.pow((y-y1), 2))));
    }
}

public class Target{
    private Location loc;
    private double speed;
    private String type;
    private boolean threat;
    private static int count = 0;

    public Target(double x, double y, double speed){
        loc = new Location(x, y);
        this.speed = speed;
        if(speed<500)
            type="Helicopter";
        else type="Jet";
        threat = false;
        count++;
    }

    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }

    public double getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public void setSpeed(double speed) {
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public Location getLoc() {
        return loc;
    }

    public void setLoc(Location loc) {
        this.loc = loc;
    }

    public boolean isThreat(Location L){
        if(loc.getDistance(L)<100){
            threat=true;}
        else threat=false;
        return threat;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Target is " + getType() + ", speed= " + getSpeed() + "mph, [Location: x=" + loc.getX()+ "; y=" + loc.getY() + "]";
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm still having some issues in the main method.. still confused about how i'm supposed to get x and y from the user

Create an array of 4 targets with data fields’ values given by the user.
• Display the distance of the first target to the location L.
• Change the location of the first target in the array. Read the new values of x & y from the user.
• Display the location of targets that are threats to L.
• Increase by 5 the speed of “Jet” targets.
• Count the number of targets whose speed is greater than the speed of the last target in the array.
• Display information on all targets.

Comment: @Ren I think you better do more research on Java and more importantly, _try_ more! After that, you should ask another question because the things you don't know how to do are no longer relevent to this one. Remember to show what you've tried!

Answer (score 0):

Location.getDistance() can not be used in this way because this not static method.

Technical solution is either change getDistance to static or create object of Location to call getDistance.

In this case from main method pass Location (variable l) to constructor of Target and inside constructor set Target instance variable loc with Location object passed and use this.loc to call getDistance()